# How to play videos from a Google Drive link?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

In my app, I want to play videos from a Google Drive link. I have tried using `VideoPlayerController`

```dart
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxxxx');
```

but can't play it. Its shown black and when I played it, nothing seem anything.

Maybe someone can help me. Suggestion really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After search around the web, finally found the answer. So, if we want to play video from Google Drive, we must get **direct download link** from our video. In example, we got this link from our video in google drive 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxxxx'.
And we can put direct download link into :

```
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=xxxxxxxx');
```

Then the video can be play.

Comment: How to get this download link to play video.

Answer (score -1):

i think you are using 'video_player 0.10.10' library.

**It is useful to review the documentation on [puv.dev.](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)**

If you are using IOS emulators, you should pay attention to this warning

> 'Warning: The video player is not functional on iOS simulators. An iOS
>   device must be used during development / testing. '

Add the following entry to your Info.plist file, located in  /ios/Runner/Info.plist:

```
<Key> nsapptransportsecurity </ key>
<Dict>
   <Key> nsallowsarbitraryloads </ key>
   <True/>
</ Dict>
```

Android

Ensure the following permission is present in your Android Manifest file, located in  /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using video_player 0.10.10.  Both of them already placed.