# Source Error occurs when google drive video plays with file id using video player in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, flutter-video-player

I found some example using video player at [How to play videos from a Google Drive link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691514/how-to-play-videos-from-a-google-drive-link) I also tried like this but source error occur.

W/_drive_demo_ap(14285): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (light greylist, reflection)
I/ExoPlayerImpl(14285): Init 5c3cc21 [ExoPlayerLib/2.12.1] [HWJKM-H, JKM-LX2, HUAWEI, 28]
V/AudioManager(14285): getStreamVolume  streamType: 3 volume: 7
V/AudioManager(14285): isStreamMute   streamType: 3
V/AudioManager(14285): getStreamMaxVolume  treamType: 3
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:554)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor) could read the stream.
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1024)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal(14285):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
I/flutter (14285): PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)

Here my code:

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1mlIaLXrBdqdKCG5WvPGiLpQRNUTKqVOf')
      ..initialize().then((_) {      
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.isInitialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

This is driving me crazy. Please help me guys

Comment: ANy solution? pls share

Comment: did you solved it ?